# Merging data frames by selecting for correct value

Tags: r

I have a data frame called "ref" that contains information that allows mapping of gene entrez ID to the gene's start and end positions. I have another data frame "ori_data" where each row contains unique mutations from samples, which gives a genomic position. I am trying to assign each position given in "ori_data" to map to information on "ref" in order to assign entrez ID to each mutation. I have tried a for loop to match for the same chromosome, and then select for positions in "ori_data" that fall between the coordinates in "ref" though I have not been successful. The "ori_data" dataset is over 1 million rows, so I'm not sure a for loop is an efficient solution. Note that many positions will be mapped to the same entrez ID in my real dataset. "Final" is what I want to happen- which would just add a column for entrezID according to chromosome/position. TYIA!

```
ref = data.frame("EntrezID" = c(1, 10, 100, 1000), "Chromosome" = c("19", "8", "20", "18"), "txStarts" = c("58345182", "18391281", "44619518", "27950965"), "txEnds" = c("58353492", "18401215", "44651758", "28177130"))

ori_data = data.frame("Chromosome" = c("19", "8", "20", "18"), "Pos" = c("58345186", "18401213", "44619519", "27950966"),
             "Sample" = c("HCC1", "HCC2", "HCC1", "HCC3"))

final = data.frame("Chromosome" = c("19", "8", "20", "18"), "Pos" = c("58345186", "18401213", "44619519", "27950966"),
               "Sample" = c("HCC1", "HCC2", "HCC1", "HCC3"), "EntrezID" = c(1,10,100,1000))
```

I have tried this line of code and I'm unsure as to why it does not work.

```
for (i in 1:dim(ori_data)[1])
{
  for (j in 1:dim(ref)[1])
  {
    ID = which(ori_data[i, "Chromosome"] == ref[j, 
     "Chromosome"])
    if (length(ID) > 0)
    {
      Pos = ori_data[ID, "POS"]
      IDj = which(Pos >= ref[j, "txStarts"] & Pos <= 
           ref[j, "txEnds"])
      print(IDj)
      if (length(IDj) > 0)
       {
        ori_data = cbind("Entrez" = ref[IDj, 
                  "EntrezID"], ori_data)
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In base `apply` could be used to find matches per row for *Chromosome* and test if *Pos* is in the range of *txStarts* *txEnds*.

```
ori_data$EntrezID <- apply(ori_data[c("Chromosome", "Pos")], 1, \(x)
  ref$EntrezID[ref$Chromosome == x["Chromosome"] &
    x["Pos"] >= ref$txStarts & x["Pos"] <= ref$txEnds][1])
ori_data
#  Chromosome      Pos Sample EntrezID
#1         19 58345186   HCC1        1
#2          8 18401213   HCC2       10
#3         20 44619519   HCC1      100
#4         18 27950966   HCC3     1000
```

A version which could be faster:

```
lup <- list2env(split(ref[c("EntrezID", "txStarts", "txEnds")], ref$Chromosome))
ori_data$EntrezID <- Map(\(x, y) {
  . <- get(x, envir=lup)
  .$EntrezID[y >= .$txStarts & y <= .$txEnds][1]
}, ori_data$Chromosome, ori_data$Pos)
```

Or another way but not keeping the original order. (If original order is important, have a look at `unsplit`.)

```
#Assuming you have many rows with same Chromosome
x <- split(ori_data, ori_data$Chromosome)

#Assuming you have also here many rows with same Chromosome
lup <- split(ref[c("EntrezID", "txStarts", "txEnds")], ref$Chromosome)

#Now I am soting this by the names of x - try which Method ist faster
#Method 1:
lup <- lup[names(x)]
#Method 2:
lup <- mget(names(x), list2env(lup))

res <- do.call(rbind, Map(\(a, b) {
  cbind(a, b[1][a$Pos >= b[[2]] &  a$Pos <= b[[3]]][1])
}, x, lup))
```

Comment: I like this solution as it's very straightforward but I'm unsure why it won't finish running. No error message- but let in run for 30 minutes with no result. The dataset "dna" it's working on is around 160,000 rows so it seems it should be able to complete faster.

Comment: It will need time, because it is making the comparison for each element of *dna* with each in *ref*. But maybe the new version in the answer is faster.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `sqldf`, which should also be efficient for a large dataframe.

```
library(tibble)
library(sqldf)

as_tibble(sqldf("select dna.*, ref.EntrezID from dna
                join ref on dna.Pos > ref.'txStarts' and 
                dna.Pos < ref.'txEnds'"))
```

Another option using `fuzzy_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

dna %>%
  fuzzy_join(ref %>% select(-Chromosome), by = c("Pos" = "txStarts", "Pos" = "txEnds"),
             match_fun = list(`>`, `<`)) %>%
  select(names(dna), EntrezID)
```

**Output**

```
  Chromosome      Pos Sample EntrezID
1         19 58345186   HCC1        1
2          8 18401213   HCC2       10
3         20 44619519   HCC1      100
4         18 27950966   HCC3     1000
```

Comment: I believe this works by chance, I think we want to inner join by Chromosome first, then filter to keep acceptable Pos

Answer (score 0):

If the 'Pos', 'txStarts', 'txEnds' are numeric, then we can use non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dna)[ref, EntrezID := i.EntrezID, 
    on = .(Chromosome, Pos > txStarts, Pos <txEnds)]
```

-output

```
> dna
   Chromosome      Pos Sample EntrezID
       <char>    <num> <char>    <num>
1:         19 58345186   HCC1        1
2:          8 18401213   HCC2       10
3:         20 44619519   HCC1      100
4:         18 27950966   HCC3     1000
```

#### data

```
dna <- type.convert(dna, as.is = TRUE)
ref <- type.convert(ref, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Any way to select for matching chromosome numbers within this function? Seems the most efficient solution, but I noticed that some chromosome numbers weren't matching up between sets

Comment: @jimuq233 sorry, i didn't notice the `Chromosome`.  You have to add the `Chromosome` as well in the join. (updated)